# why this is ref to window Obj here?

Tags: javascript

I am new to js and felt that I understood the concept of **this** until I came across.

```
        function TopLevelFn(){
            var obj = {
                empId : 232
            };
            console.log('TopLevelFn() empId :' + obj.empId);
            innerFn();

            function innerFn(){
               //why this points to window object...
                console.log('innerFn() empId :' + this.obj.empId); 

            }
        }

        var register = new TopLevelFn();
```

If I understood it clearly the innerFn() is called from TopLevelFn() so the invoking obj and **this** should be ref to TopLevelFn()?

Comment: Context depends on how you invoke the function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't explain this scenario to me. this should be having the obj in its context because its invoked from the enclosing fn.

Comment: No it should not. You misunderstand. Just because the function is within another function doesn't mean anything. Context is determined by how you invoke the function.

Answer (score 0):

Context depends on how you invoke the function. Your case is described in ECMAScript spec [10.4.3 Entering Function Code](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3):

> The following steps are performed when control enters the execution
>   context for function code contained in function object F, a caller
>   provided *thisArg*, and a caller provided *argumentsList*:
>
> 1. If the function code is strict code, set the ThisBinding to *thisArg*.
> 2. Else if thisArg is **null** or **undefined**, set the ThisBinding to the
>      global object.

Since you don't provide a `thisArg` the function is executed in global context.

Now you may ask how to provide `thisArg` value? ECMAScript defines three methods to explicitly specify execution context: [`Function.prototype.call`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.4), [`Function.prototype.apply`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.3) and [`Function.prototype.bind`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5) (returns new function). In your case you can use `call` like this:

```
innerFn.call(this);
```

in this case `innerFn` will be invoked in context of `this` object. Otherwise `innerFn()` will have global context.